# Snowflake error in JavaScript procedure column index/name does not exists in resultSet getColumnValue

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am having a procedure on snowflake which executing the following query:

```
select
    array_size(split($1, ',')) as NO_OF_COL,
    split($1, ',') as COLUMNS_ARRAY
from
    @mystage/myfile.csv(file_format => 'ONE_COLUMN_FILE_FORMAT')
limit 1;
```

And the result would be like:

[image]

Why I run this query in a procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADD_TEMPORARY_TABLE(TEMP_TABLE_NAME STRING, FILE_FULL_PATH STRING, ONE_COLUMN_FORMAT_FILE STRING, FILE_FORMAT_NAME STRING)
RETURNS variant
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
try{
    var final_result = [];
    var nested_obj = {};
    var nbr_rows = 0;
    var NO_OF_COL = 0;
    var COLUMNS_ARRAY = [];
    var get_length_and_columns_array = "select array_size(split($1,',')) as NO_OF_COL, "+
        "split($1,',') as COLUMNS_ARRAY from "+FILE_FULL_PATH+" "+ 
        "(file_format=>"+ONE_COLUMN_FORMAT_FILE+") limit 1";
    
    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: get_length_and_columns_array});
    var array_result = stmt.execute();
    array_result.next();
    //return array_result.getColumnValue('COLUMNS_ARRAY');
    NO_OF_COL = array_result.getColumnValue('NO_OF_COL');
    COLUMNS_ARRAY = array_result.getColumnValue('COLUMNS_ARRAY');
    return COLUMNS_ARRAY;
}
...
$$;
```

It will return an error as the following:

> {
>
> "code": 100183,
>
> "message": "Given column name/index does not exist: NO_OF_COL",
>
> "stackTraceTxt": "At ResultSet.getColumnValue, line 16 position 29",
>
> "state": "P0000",
>
> "toString": {}
>
> }

The other issue is if I keep trying, it will return the desired array, but most of the times is returning this error.

Comment: if this is sometimes run successfully , then it might be your data  or your csv file

Answer (score 1):

> *The other issue is if I keep trying, it will return the desired array*

If it works one time and not another time, my educated guess is that the stored procedure is called from different schemas.

> [Querying stage](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-stage.html)
>
> ```
> ( FILE_FORMAT => '<namespace>.<named_file_format>' )
> ```
>
> If referencing a file format in the current namespace for your user session, **you can omit the single quotes around the format identifier.**

---

In the standalone query we can see:

```
select
   array_size(split($1, ',')) as NO_OF_COL,
    split($1, ',') as COLUMNS_ARRAY
from
@mystage/myfile.csv(file_format => 'ONE_COLUMN_FILE_FORMAT')
                                  >-<                    >-<
```

But in the stored procedure body:

```
"(file_format=>"+ONE_COLUMN_FORMAT_FILE+") limit 1";
               --here the text is appended, but without wrapping with ''

=>
"(file_format=>'"+ONE_COLUMN_FORMAT_FILE+"') limit 1";
```

Suggestion: always provide file format as as string wrapped with `'`, preferably prefixed with  namespace `'<schema_name>.<format_name>'`.